# Force NSStackView to Hug Content

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a vertical `NSStackView` as the `contentView` of a resizable `NSPanel`. The contents of this stack view are configured dynamically. Every row hugs its content vertically with priority `.required`.

Now if I set the stack views vertical hugging priority to `.required`, I expected the stack view to prevent vertical resizing.

How can I force the stack view to fit its subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch to `NSGridView`, since `NSStackView` apparently does not support content hugging at all.